# What is a compact, embeddable Servlet container suitable for use with Vaadin?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, vaadin

I'm developing a desktop application in Java, and I want to use [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) as a user interface for it (so the user will access it through their web browser).  I'm using Maven, so it is greatly preferred if all of my dependencies are available through Maven (Vaadin is).

Vaadin requires a servlet container, so I need to find a servlet container that I can embed in my app, which won't significantly increase the size of my distributable file (I'm hoping to keep it under several megabytes).

I looked at Jetty, but the latest version supported as a Maven dependency that I could find is 5.1.10, which is ancient.  There is a Maven plugin, but that tries to take over control of starting and stopping your entire app, which isn't appropriate here (the UI, which Jetty will be part of, is just a small part of the overall app).

Can anyone recommend a small, easily embeddable servlet container that might be suitable for this?  Extra points if you can provide pointers on how to use it together with Vaadin :-)

Comment: ibiblio has the latest and greatest jetty in its maven repository: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Jetty 8 with Maven. The artifact changed name to jetty-server and moved to Eclipse infrascruture.
Link for the tutorial: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin
Basicaly:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Run

```
mvn jetty:run
```

And you are done.

Comment: And if you don't want the plugin, here is the Hello World example running from a main class: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_and_Maven_HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7 is [embeddable](http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/) as well.